# Flutter : Instance of Future<dynamic>

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to print a value returned from a function to the screen.

Function:

`calculation.dart`:

```
  Future<dynamic> getTotalCost(BuildContext context) async {
    final user = Provider.of<Userr?>(context, listen: false);
    double totalCost = 0.0;
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('myOrders')
        .doc(user?.uid)
        .collection('items')
        .get();
    for (var doc in snapshot.docs) {
      totalCost += doc["price"];
    }
    print(totalCost.toString());
    return totalCost.toString();
  }
```

But instead printing the value , it prints Instance of Future.

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text('Item total', style: textStyle),
    Text('${ Provider.of<Calculations>(context, listen: false).getTotalCost(context).toString()}', style: textStyle),
   ],
),
```

I also know the reason that this is due to the function is asynchronous, it returns future object instead of actual value. But I need to know how can I change the above code in order to print the actual value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: Provider.of<Calculations>(context, listen: false).getTotalCost(context),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Item total', style: textStyle),
          Text('${snapshot.data}', style: textStyle),
        ],
      );
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("Error: ${snapshot.error.toString()}");
    } else {
      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  },
),
```

Comment: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<Object?>?'.  Got this error in the second line.

Comment: @AswinB sorry, that was my fault. I edited

Answer (score 0):

In order to reduce the number of `Widget` rebuild, and for performance optimization, I suggest to only wrap the `Widget` to update with the `Future` value.

By doing so, you limit the `Widget` tree in the `builder` of the `FutureBuilder` to the strict necessary.

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Item total', style: textStyle),
        FutureBuilder(
          future: Provider.of<Calculations>(context, listen: false)
              .getTotalCost(context),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text('${snapshot.data}', style: textStyle);
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("Error: ${snapshot.error.toString()}");
            } else {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
```